# What is a .qst file?

Tags: c#

I am a java developer by training , and I got a vary small C# university project to make small changes in. Inside there is a .qst file that holds some data. what is a .qst file, and why when I looked a bit in Google it says it is called a "quest file"

EDIT: this is not a graphic file, It is a text file. in the config file of the project there is the following:

```
        <setting name="QuestFile" serializeAs="String">
            <value>Quest.qst</value>
        </setting>
```

Comment: Is the text easily readable, and consistent? It sounds like your lecturer has given you a QuestFile to parse. The assignment must have some detail on what you need to do with it.

Comment: The text <b>is</b> easily readable and consistent. But what is a QuestFile in the C# world?

Comment: The answers below say it is a graphing file not a graphic file. I.E it contains data for creating graphs.  It  is unrelated to the c# language or the .net framework.

Answer (score 0):

From [Mr. Google](http://www.ehow.com/facts_5697750_file-extension-qst_.html). it seems to be some sort of Graphing file

Answer (score 0):

"QST file is a KaleidaGraph Style. KaleidaGraph is a data analysis and graphing program for use with the Windows and Macintosh platforms." from [this](http://www.filesuffix.com/extension/qst.html)